# Spark metrics are empty

Tags: apache-spark

Query finished successfully, data appeared in the sink.
But the listener got empty Metrics:

```
  spark.listenerManager.register(new QueryExecutionListener {
      override def onSuccess(funcName: String, qe: QueryExecution, durationNs: Long): Unit = {
        println(qe.observedMetrics)
        println(qe.executedPlan.metrics)
      }

      override def onFailure(funcName: String, qe: QueryExecution, exception: Exception): Unit = {
      //pass
      }
  })
```

result:

```
Map()
Map()
```

Why? How to tell spark to collect these metrics?

**edit:**

Spark 3.1.2 on K8s
(just used the example from the spark documentation)

```
 val spark = SparkSession
   .builder()
   .appName("test-app")
   .getOrCreate()

// at this point comes the 'spark.listenerManager.register' part

val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port")
  .option("subscribe", "input")
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1000)
  .load()

val ds = df
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port")
  .option("topic", "output")
  .start()

ds.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Could you put the full code here? I just tried on spark 3.2.1, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryExecutionListener` is for batch job, for stream job, it should be:

```
val spark: SparkSession = ...

spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {
    override def onQueryStarted(queryStarted: QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {
        println("Query started: " + queryStarted.id)
    }
    override def onQueryTerminated(queryTerminated: QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {
        println("Query terminated: " + queryTerminated.id)
    }
    override def onQueryProgress(queryProgress: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
        println("Query made progress: " + queryProgress.progress)
    }
})
```

You can refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#reporting-metrics-programmatically-using-asynchronous-apis